# von Neumann on the Hamiltonian

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, textbook-erratum

I'm reading von Neumann's book on QM and I'm slightly confused by a simple point. He writes,

> "The energy is a given function of the coordinates and their time derivatives: $E = L(q_1,..,q_k;\dot{q}_1,...,\dot{q}_k) = H(q_1,...,q_k;p_1,...,p_k)$. (This $H$ is the Hamiltonian function.)

This quote comes from chapter 1. Does $L(....)$ denote the Lagrangian? Why does the second equality hold?

Comment: It seems to me that the statement is written in this way to emphasize that energy can be written *as a function* of the generalized coordinates and velocities, and by finding the generalized momenta we can also express energy *as a function* of generalized coordinates and momenta. The second equality should only underscore the fact that energy itself, is a **given function** of the coordinates and their derivatives (though it might be reached via different formalizations) as stated in the first part of the expression.

Comment: I have no deeper reasoning for this, we already know L and H are different functions that stand for different things at the simplest level.

Comment: if $H$ does not explicitly depend on time, as you have written it, then it is a constant of time hence $E=H$

Comment: @hyportnex Aren't the $q_i$ and $p_i$ typically functions of time, so $H$ is in fact, implicitly, a function of time?

Comment: yes they are, but the question if it is *explicitly* a function of time (same for the lagrangian $\mathcal L$) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics

Comment: @GulceKardes So, in this case $L(...)$ doesn't stand for the Lagrangian?

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/362229/condition-that-the-lagrangian-energy-function-h-equiv-sum-i-frac-partial-l-p).

Answer (score 2):

No, *L*  ***does not stand for the Lagrangian*** $\cal L$: it stands for the "energy function" , ("as a rule, a quadratic function of the $\dot{q}$s"), an evident constant of the motion,
$$
L(q_i, \dot{q}_i) = \frac{\partial \cal{L}}{\partial\dot{q}_i}\dot{q}_i - \cal{L},
$$
so, basically, $\sim {\cal L} + 2V(q)$ for the quadratic function he is considering, a deeply unfortunate convention, ipso facto... (the energy function in the Lagrangian formalism), is all.

The momenta *p* are then the *same* gradients of $\cal L$ or *L* !   Storm in a teacup. Are you overthinking it?

The equality $L(q,\dot{q})=H(q,p)$ holds as usual in the Legendre transform transition from Lagrangian to Hamiltonian mechanics.

PS. <sub>von Neumann was famously too quick to imagine he'd have to explain things fully, preferring to rely on his proverbial well-meaning intelligent reader. Wait until you get to III.5.F, which has victimized generations of readers, and required a famous theorem to be declared confusing, after all.</sub>